# External Data Refresh Failed DATABASENAME Tfs_Analysis Work Item

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, tfs-analysis

i have excel reports accessing analysis database. they are uploaded to sharepoint.
After upload they dont work anymore.

secure store credentials for analysis database have been created. connection string in excel is the same as in the other working reports that where already there.
user for the reports is the sharepoint service account.
user has full access to tfs, sharepoint, tfs database server and analysis server

when refreshing the report on my pc trough sharepoint web portal, the graphs get empty. refreshing it on other PC's in the network, the error comes up.

any ideas?

Comment: What're detail steps you do? Do you [configure Excel Services data refresh by using external data connections](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525341.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the cause for the error message was different date/time formats in the excel file and the server.

The file has TT.MM.JJ Germnan format, the server expects english format.